# Custom Adapter in Android listview has many ifs

Tags: android, if-statement, android-arrayadapter

I have an adapter for a `listview`, which extends the base `ArrayAdapter`. The whole logic of populating a list member is in if blocks. Since there are just 4 fields, it's not a big deal. But what if you have a more complex `adapter`?
Is it a good practice to use ifs for this, or a more elegant solution should be implemented(performance wise)?

```
   if (promo != null) {

        if(!(promo.getItemType().equals(""))){
            holder.item1.setText("Item group :"+ promo.getItemType());
        }
        else if(!(promo.getItemCode().equals(""))){
            holder.item1.setText(promo.getItemCode());
        }

        else if(!(promo.getCustCode().equals(""))){
            holder.item1.setText(promo.getCustCode());
        }
        else if(!(promo.getCustType().equals(""))){
            holder.item1.setText("Clients from: "+ promo.getCustType());
        }

        //set ItemRelation
        if( !(promo.getItemType().equals("")) ){
            holder.item2.setText( promo.getItemCode() );

        }else if(promo.getItemType().equals("1")){
            holder.item2.setText("Group " + promo.getItemCode());

        }else{
            holder.item2.setText("All items");
        }

        if(promo.getPromoType().equals("1")){
            holder.item3.setText(promo.getPercent() + "%");
        }else{
            holder.item3.setText("Sum " + promo.getSalesPrice());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any special technique to avoid 'ifs' but there should not be any problem in using multiple if statements. but if you will use some kind of heavy looping in your if blocks then it can effect the performance of your programe

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't shared the code, it would be inappropriate to provide a more elegant solution. However, using a complex adapter doesn't always mean that you will have performance issues. It just has to follow good practices, like using a ViewHolder to help listview recycle the views.